# How to have automatic ordering of floats?

Tags: floats

I tend to place my "float code" after the first call out (i.e., `\ref`) to the float. While I am drafting a document the first call out may change and I feel like I waste time finding the first call out and moving the float code to the correct place. Sometimes I also have float code that may or may not get used (e.g., a table that I am not sure I am going to include). What I would like to be able to do is define a `figures` environment and redefine `\ref` so that I can type something like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
This is a reference to figure~\ref{fig:D}.

This is a reference to figure~\ref{fig:A}.

This is a reference to figure~\ref{fig:C}.

This is a reference to figure~\ref{fig:C}.

\begin{figures}
  \begin{figure}\caption{This is figure A.}\label{fig:A}\end{figure}
  \begin{figure}\caption{This is figure B.}\label{fig:B}\end{figure}
  \begin{figure}\caption{This is figure C.}\label{fig:C}\end{figure}
  \begin{figure}\caption{This is figure D.}\label{fig:D}\end{figure}
\end{figures}
\end{document}
```

and have LaTeX realize that what I want is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
This is a reference to figure~\ref{fig:D}\begin{figure}\caption{This is figure D.}\label{fig:D}\end{figure}.

This is a reference to figure~\ref{fig:A}\begin{figure}\caption{This is figure A.}\label{fig:A}\end{figure}.

This is a reference to figure~\ref{fig:C}\begin{figure}\caption{This is figure C.}\label{fig:C}\end{figure}.

This is a reference to figure~\ref{fig:C}.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way is to  put each float in a separate file of the form

```
 \expandafter\ifx\csname r@fig:A\endcsname\relax\else\expandafter\endinput\fi
 \begin{figure}
  .....
 \caption{This is figure A.}\label{fig:A}
 \end{figure}
```

then use

```
\input{figAfile}\ref{fig:A}
```

the figure will only be set once even if you input it multiple times
as the `\ifx` test checks whether the label is defined and stops reading the file if it is.