# Add text at end of paragraph that has an \hbox:n

Tags: paragraphs, latex3

This is a follow on to my previous question about the [LaTeX3 `\hbox:n`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/458122/where-does-the-par-come-from-with-hboxn) behavior. I am trying to automatically add text at the end of a paragraph by redefining `\par` in the middle of the paragraph. This is related to me trying to hack the [`endfloat`](https://ctan.org/pkg/endfloat) package to handle floats in the middle of a paragraph that come about because I want to [automatically order floats](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/195838/how-to-have-automatic-ordering-of-floats).

Even with all of that, I can reduce my problem down to a simple MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}

% For my actual use case
\usepackage[backref = true]{enotez}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{endfloat}

\makeatletter
\def\foo{\def\par{Hello World\global\let\par\@@par\par}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

A \foo\hbox{B} C

A \foo\ExplSyntaxOn\hbox:n{B}{}\ExplSyntaxOff C

A\foo\endnote{B}C

The full actual use case is that 

A
\begin{figure}
MY FIGURE
\end{figure}
B

is wrong since I want ``figure about here'' to be at the end of the paragraph and not between A and B

This fixes the problem

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\floatplace}[1]{%
  \gdef\par{%
    \global\let\par\@@par%
    \par%
    %\begin{center}%
      [\csname #1name\endcsname~\csname thepost#1\endcsname\ about here.]%
    %\end{center}%
    \par%
  }%
}
\makeatother

A
\begin{figure}
MY FIGURE
\end{figure}
B

but then things get broken again with the endnote

A
\begin{figure}
MY FIGURE
\end{figure}
B\endnote{broken again}C


\end{document}
```

In the construct with the `\hbox:n` I would like the extra text "Hello World", to be at the end of the paragraph (like it is with the `\hbox` construct).

My real use case is very much like `A\foo\endnote{B}C` with both the `enotez` and `hyperref` packages loaded. I am, likely naively, assuming that if I can get text to the end of a paragraph that has an `\hbox:n` in it, that my actual use case will also work.

Comment: Might be worth raising on LaTeX-L: we could alter the definition used in `\hbox:n` (it _seemed_ safe enough, but perhaps we overlooked a use case).

Comment: This might be an XY-question. Maybe some more details could be useful. In any case, `\global\let\par\@@par` is quite dubious.

Comment: @egreg I put my full example in. It is probably still an x-y problem, but ...

Comment: Saying the \global\let\par\@@par is dubious is putting it mildly, I would just say it is wrong and breaks 2e  interfaces.  And no @JosephWright I think we should not alter the interfaces for that. The idea of jumping ahead to the \par and then doing something is interesting, but  since anything between here an then can start a new vertical list with \par's inside this is bound to fail in many ways unless one carefully checks which \par is reached ... that just for starters, and as I said setting \par globally this way is ... hmmm

Comment: @FrankMittelbach is there a way to jump ahead to the end of a paragraph?

Comment: @FrankMittelbach All I was thinking is we can avoid having a `\par` in `\color_group_end:`, keeping it purely for the `\vbox:n` case in the same way LaTeX2e does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LaTeX 2e has some internal assumptions about how `\par` can be modified locally to achieve special effects. Doing global assignments to it, will end up causing a lof ot trouble in one or the other situation (nesting of elements that use different setting which are then completely destroyed).

The idea of catching the end of the current paragraph by redefining `\par` is interesting, but because of the complexity of nesting one can't ever rely on that the end of the current paragraph is the next `\par` command we see even if we are in the middle of that paragraph. The issue with `\hbox:n` is only one example and it is easy to contruct arbitrary many others. Thus changing its implementation will not resolve the problem (though it may be advisable for other reasons :-) ).

As to the question "s there a way to jump ahead to the end of a paragraph?" the answer depends on what is meant here. Jumping ahead, not really, but sizing control, perhaps. How reliably I'm not 100% sure.

Basically, eTeX offers us \currentgrouplevel to inspect at which grouping level we currently are. So assuming we are in fact inside the paragraph we want to find the end of, then we could record the current grouping level and the current definition of `\par` and then change `\par` in a way it first inspects the grouping level and then acts depending on what it find:

- if the grouping level is the same as the one we started from, we should have reached the end of the current paragraph and we should do whatever we want to do (after having restored `\par` to its former definition!)
- if the grouping level is higher, we are in some inner object and we should execute the saved definition of `\par` because this is not the end of our paragraph. Note that if the inner object itself has changed par our test wouldn't apply and all is fine too.
- if the grouping level is lower we somehow manged screw up (because theoretically this shouldn't be possible)

Guess this is roughly the direction in which I would go if trying to implement such a functionality.